# In url("../(folder-name)/(image-name)"), what does "../" represent?

Tags: css, url

```css
background-image: url("../images/intro-1.jpg");
```

In the above piece of CSS code, I am having trouble figuring out why that `..` is used.

Answer (score 2):

This is used to get out of current or access parent directory:

- `./` means current directory
- `../` means parent directory

Have a look at [Paths explained: Absolute, relative, UNC, and URL](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/supplement/pathnames-explained-absolute-relative-unc-and-url.htm).